# Integration in R with integrate function

Tags: r, integral

```
library(pbivnorm)

rho <- 0.5
f1 <- function(x, y) {
  pbivnorm(log(x)-10, log(y)-10, rho)*(exp(-(log(x)-10)^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)*x))*(exp(-(log(y)-10)^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)*y))
}
integration1 <- round(integrate(function(y) {
  sapply(y, function(y) {
    integrate(function(x) f1(x,y), 0, Inf, rel.tol = 1e-12)$value
  })
}, 0, Inf, rel.tol = 1e-12)$value, 10)
```

This integration should be around 0.3, but R gives 0. Could anyone point out the problem? What is the best function for integral in R? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add some details as to what integral you're trying to calculate? Also, always explicitly include which non base R libraries you're using (`pbivnorm` is not base R). Lastly, `round(integrate(...))` looks like a bad idea. Are you sure you want to be rounding the result from `integrate`? Note that `round(0.3) = 0`!

Comment: I would like to integration f1 above. It is round to 10 digits, so round(0.3, 10) = 0.3, not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `cubature` can solve the problem giving the expected result. The function must be rewritten as a one argument function, and the values for `x` and `y` set in the function body.

```
library(cubature)

f2 <- function(X) {
  x <- X[1]
  y <- X[2]
  pbivnorm(log(x)-10, log(y)-10, rho)*(exp(-(log(x)-10)^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)*x))*(exp(-(log(y)-10)^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)*y))
}

hcubature(f2, c(0, 0), c(Inf, Inf))
#$integral
#[1] 0.2902153
#
#$error
#[1] 2.863613e-06
#
#$functionEvaluations
#[1] 7599
#
#$returnCode
#[1] 0
```

**Edit.**

Following the [OP's second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433924/integration-in-r-with-integrate-function/59434024#comment105053950_59434024), here is the integral computed with `hcubature`

```
f3 <- function(x) {
  pnorm(log(x)-10.2)*(exp(-(log(x)-10)^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)*x)) 
} 

hcubature(f3, lowerLimit = 0, upperLimit = Inf, tol = 1e-12)$integral 
#[1] 0.4437685
```

Comment: f3 <- function(x) {
  pnorm(log(x)-10.2)*(exp(-(log(x)-10)^2/2)/(sqrt(2*pi)*x))
}
cubintegrate(f3, lower = 0, upper = Inf, method = "divonne", relTol = 1e-05, absTol = 1e-12)$integral                                                                                                                                           The integration of f3 should be 0.4438, however, this code gives 0. Could anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: @user53154 Once again `hcubature` gave the right result. As for thee reason why your code gave `0`, I cannot say without seeing the exact code you ran.

Comment: Hi Rui, could you please help me the following integration using hcubature? f1 <- function(X) {
  x <- X[1]
  y <- X[2]
  (pnorm(x-10)-pnorm(y-10))^2*(exp(-((x-10)^2-2*rho*(x-10)*(y-10)+(y-10)^2)/(2*(1-rho^2)))/(2*pi*sqrt(1-rho^2)))
}
library(cubature)
round(hcubature(f1, c(-Inf, -Inf), c(Inf, Inf), tol = 1e-12)$integral, 6) this gave 0, but the correct answer should be 0.1348. Thank you so much.