# 'Strange' behavior of integrate function with truncdist in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration, integrate

Mathematically the following is impossible for

```
library(truncdist)
q = function(x, L, R ) dtrunc(x, "exp", rate=0.1, a=L,b=R) 
integrate(q, L=2, R=3, lower  =0, upper = 27 )
integrate(q, L=2, R=3, lower  =0, upper = 29 )
integrate(q, L=2, R=3, lower  =27, upper = 29 )
integrate(q, L=2, R=3, lower  =0, upper = 30 )
```

We found the first integral giving a positive number, the second one evaluating to zero by adding the third interval which integrates itself to zero. Is this an issue in `integrate` or `truncdist`?

We can use the following to find more such issues

```
z=numeric()
for(i in 1:50){
  z[i]=integrate(q, L=2, R=3, lower  =0, upper = i)$value
}
```

What do I need to do to find the correct integrals (which all are 1 when integrating from 0 to `i>=3`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help("integrate")`:

> Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the function on a finite set of points. If the function is approximately constant (in particular, zero) over nearly all its range it is possible that the result and error estimate may be seriously wrong.

You found an example of this:

```
curve(q(x, 2, 3), from = -1, to = 30)
```

[image: resulting plot]

You shouldn't integrate distribution density functions numerically. Use the cumulative distribution function:

```
diff(ptrunc(c(0, 29), "exp", rate = 0.1, a = 2, b = 3))
#[1] 1
```

Comment: I would like to but in my application the integral is defined across the product of the density with another function of x and x itself. So I think I cannot do this?

Comment: Can't say without specifics. But if you know the bounds of the truncation, you only need to integrate the product within these bounds. That avoids the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative answer in this post: [Integration in R with integrate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433924/integration-in-r-with-integrate-function)

Using `hcubature` the problem can be solved numerically, which is a closer answer to my original question.